# Variable not updating in while loop, python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, scope, break

I am trying to write a battleship game.  I followed the course on codecademy and I continued with the game I wrote there, but I separated things into their own modules and created classes.  I'm still very new to python and programming in general.  I've taken a CS course before and I'm now working through CS50x on EDX

In my program I declare a variable called play_again and set it to 0.  I then use a while statement to run my game with `while play_again != 2:`

This is essentially my "Main Menu" for the game.

```
play_again = 0

while play_again != 2:

    if play_again == 0:
        print("Would you like to play a game of Battleship?")
        print("Enter 1 to play")
        print("Enter 2 to exit")
        play_again = int(input("Make a selection: "))

    if play_again == 1:
```

This block is where I run into problems it is nested in the `if` block above after some other code that just creates a game board and a ship to find.

```
        for turn in range(4):
            print("Turn: ", turn + 1)
            guess_row = int(input("Guess Row: ")) - 1 # the "-1"s here 
compensate for our count starting at 0
            guess_col = int(input("Guess Col: ")) - 1

            #checks to see if the users guess is correct
            if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
                print("Congratulations! You sank my battleship!")
                play_again == 0
                break
```

I'm really having issues with this break statement.  I'm using Pycharm and in the debugger the variable `play_again` is never set to 0.  It stays 1 from the "Main Menu" and I cannot for the life of me figure out why it's not changing.  I feel its something super simple.  I feel it has something to do with the way scope works in python, but the variable is created in the same function it is used in so I'm not sure why the scope would be different between the two. Does scope change when you go into a loop?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why would `play_again` be set to 0?

Comment: It is initially set to 0 so it will run through the menu and it is set back to 0 after you win or loose to go back to that menu.

Comment: You have `play_again == 0` maybe you meant to type `play_again = 0`.

Comment: I knew it was something simple haha.  I thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `play_again == 0` maybe you meant to type `play_again = 0`.